# Rails Carrierwave url is nil unless queried again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, carrierwave

I am having an issue with carrierwave/active-record in my rails application. My problem is that the following code resolves all of the images to null

```
<% Ad.all.limit(30).each do |ad| %>
    <img src="<%= ad.carrier_image.url %>" >
<% end %>
```

Where as the following renders all the images just fine

```
<% Ad.all.limit(30).each do |ad| %>
    <img src="<%= Ad.find(ad.id).carrier_image.url %>" >
<% end %>
```

The urls are there, just on the initial loop the carrier_image does not seem to be preloaded into the active record objects I think this is an issue with my understanding of rails eager loading, but I am having trouble figuring out how one would avoid this issue

Comment: What is `carrier_image`? model or attribute?

Comment: It is an attribute that is mounted by the carrierwave  
uploader  `mount_uploader :carrier_image, ImageUploader`

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with Carrierwave.  You can use `.each` to iterate through your activerecord result set.  So, in your first example, change the first line to `<% Ad.all.limit(30).each do |ad| %>`.  I'm not sure why the second set of code renders correctly.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, both do have .each on them , edited to show that.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use the rails image_tag helper? You're also missing the brackets off the url call as per the carrierwave documentation, but I don't think that's what's causing you drama.

```
 <%= image_tag ad.carrier_image_url() %>
```

As a side note, you should really move the "Ad.all.limit(30)" out of your view if you wish to keep it all "railsy".